# MS Access query not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, case

could anybody explain me what's wrong with this query?

```
SELECT Attempts, (CASE WHEN LastLogin IS NOT NULL AND DATE_ADD(LastLogin, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)>NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Denied 
FROM tbl_loginLocks 
WHERE IP = "192.168.178.43";
```

I got an error that a operation is missing.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the actual error?

Comment: You seem to be missing the `END` of the `CASE`: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php

Comment: i think, it's should `WHERE IP = '192.168.178.43'` not `WHERE IP = "192.168.178.43"`

Comment: Add END at the end of CASE statement

Comment: I tried already with END and IIF but it's not working either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access does not have a case statement, use IIF:

```
SELECT Attempts, 
IIf(Not IsNull(LastLogin) AND DATEADD("n",1,LastLogin)>NOW(),1,0) AS Denied 
FROM tbl_loginLocks 
WHERE IP = "192.168.178.43"
```

[Dateadd](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx)
[IIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `END` at the end of the `CASE`:

```
SELECT Attempts, (CASE WHEN LastLogin IS NOT NULL AND DATE_ADD(LastLogin, INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)>NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Denied 
FROM tbl_loginLocks 
WHERE IP = '192.168.178.43';
```

Alternatively, use an IIF statement:

```
SELECT Attempts, IIF(LastLogin IS NOT NULL AND DATEADD("n", 1, LastLogin) >NOW(), 1, 0) AS Denied 
FROM tbl_loginLocks 
WHERE IP = '192.168.178.43';
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. I have got some ideas.. could it be that DATE_ADD is not supported by Access?

Comment: Very possible. I don't have Access available here. Try out @Remou's solution? He uses DATEADD. Perhaps that's the Access equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Add **END** at the end of **CASE** statement

Your **Date_Add** function is **wrong**

The Microsoft Access **DateAdd** function returns a date after which a certain time/date interval has been added.

**SYNTAX**

The syntax for the Microsoft Access DateAdd function is:

```
DateAdd ( interval, number, date )
```

Just Try this

```
SELECT Attempts, (CASE WHEN LastLogin IS NOT NULL AND DateAdd ("n",1,LastLogin)>NOW() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Denied 
FROM tbl_loginLocks 
WHERE IP = "192.168.178.43";
```